# Why the non-root user can't login with a key in putty?

Tags: users, putty, key-authentication

I read an article and found it very useful:
http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

I made two key pairs for `root` and the other user. But it only works for root

When it comes to the other one, the server shows:

```
Using username "theotheruser".
Server refused our key
theotheruser@mydomain.com's password:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check permissions for the `~/.ssh` directory for user and all files in it. The `~/.ssh` directory should have permissions `700`, while files should have permissions `600`

Comment: Also check the permissions on all directories in the path.  They should be writable only by the owner.